# How to secure a webslide site with a simple password on the first slide

Tags: javascript, html

I've used [webslides](https://webslides.tv/#slide=1) to create a web presentation hosted on a Google Drive. All the slides are loaded from one single HTML file while the transition between slides is controlled via CSS + JS in, switching between the many `<section></section>` elements within the single HTML file.

I'm looking for a simple way of securing the webslide presentation by incorporating a simple formfield in the first slide (first `<section></section>`) which will ask for an e-mail address and match it with a pre-existing list on a separate JS file in the JS folder. If the e-mail exist, the scrolling between slides or sections will be enabled. if not the scrolling will be disabled.

I am aware of the fact that this is really not so safe because a simple view-source will expose all the data however this is really a simple presentation offered only to registrants of a webinar, not something sensitive at all.

Hoping someone has some experience working with webslides who can offer a simple JS script to include in the HTML file?

Comment: Why not limit access to the file only to seminar participants by Google Drive permissions?

Comment: I use Google Drive as a hosting server via Drive to Web (https://drv.tw/). That means the presentation has a drv.tw URL which is accessible to anyone clicking it. The protection needs to be on the HTML file itself...

Comment: Well, if you distribute the link to your attendees it will be as good as distributing username/password

Comment: What happened is that when my students realized they get the slides in the URL, they started circulating the URL between them and stopped attending the actual zoom lectures. They name one or two to attend, who, in turn, send the URL to the rest. I'd like to assure attendance in the ZOOM lecture by sharing a URL to a presentation that will be navigable only to those who i listed their e-mails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with web slides and have no idea about how you implement it.
But: If you want a dead-simple and quirky solution, add a parent HTML, and use the slide as an iframe.

Over that iframe, you can place an overlay div that blocking access to slide with password input, if you match the password you can remove the overlay.

Update:

This solution is adding an overlay login form before initializing slides.

```
<style>
    /* Basic Styling for login form */

    .loginOverlay{
        position: fixed;
        right:0px; left:0px;
        top:0px; bottom:0px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .loginForm{
        width:400px;
        height: 60px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .loginForm.error{
        border:1px solid red;
    }
</style>
```

HTML Elements

```
<div class="loginOverlay" id="loginOverlay"><!-- Overlay -->
    <div class="loginForm" id="loginForm"><!-- Form -->
        <input type="text" id="uEmail"> <button onclick="checkEmail()">Login</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Scripts

```
<script>

    const loginOverlay = document.getElementById("loginOverlay"); //Reference of the overlay that blocks the access.
    const loginForm = document.getElementById("loginForm");//Reference of the form box.

    //Email list to be populated.
    let emails = [
    "a@a.com",
    "b@b.com"
    ];

    /**/

function loadJSON(file,callback) {//Function that loading a file.
    var xReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xReq.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xReq.open('GET', file, true);
    xReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xReq.readyState === 4 && xReq.status === 200) {
            callback(xReq.responseText);
        }
    };
    xReq.send(null);
}
    


    function checkEmail() {//Your login control method

        let value = document.getElementById("uEmail").value//Get value of input

        if(emails.indexOf(value)!== -1){//Is it in the list?
            loginOverlay.remove();//Remove overlay
            window.ws = new WebSlides(); //Run Slides

        }else{
            if(!loginForm.classList.contains('error')){//Is error styling added
                loginForm.classList.add("error")//Add error styling.
            }
        }
    }

    loadJSON('users.json',(list)=>{//Get your list.
        emails = JSON.parse(list);
    });
    
    </script>
```

Your users.json file

```
[
    "a@a.com",
    "b@b.com",
    "c@c.com"
]
```

Comment: I didn't think of this idea and I like it very much. Thank you. Would you happen to know how can i use a simple JS to match a password from a list of passwords in a txt file?

Comment: I believe you want the whole code to achieve your goal. I would like to remind you that StackOverflow is not a forum but more like a platform to overcome difficulties that you couldn't cope up with after you tried something. (at least from my point of view)

I might be wrong but I believe you are an educationist and I wouldn't leave your request unanswered in that light. But please consider reading the rules.

I updated my answer.